# When applying a Regex with groups to a string, is there a way to tell if there are multiple ways that those groups can be matched?

Tags: c#, regex

As an example, I have the following regex:
`^(.*)[AB]+$`
which I am matching against the string
ABBA

The entire string ABBA is a match for the regex, that is correct, however I am only able to get the value "ABB" for group 1. But the entire regex may match the given string in a number of ways. The group (.*) may also refer to the sequence A, and then [AB]+ to match the following sequence, BBA.

Is there a way to determine if there are different ways in which groups in an expression can be matched?

I am using C#, and I tried fiddling with Regex.Matches(), as well as Regex.Replace(), but I could not get the information I am after.

Comment: You should read about greedy vs lazy quantifiers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285) for example). In short `(.*)` will match as many characters as possible, giving back as necessary. So, it matches the entire string, and then gives back the last letter because that's the least that could be matched by `[AB]+`.

Comment: No, it is not how regexes work. You do not need a regex for this in the first place. Well, you can get all possible substrings and validate them with any custom regex of your choice.

Comment: Consider these two other cases: 1) If you replace the second part with `[AB]*`, then the group will match the entire string ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/wrunTf/1)). 2) If you use `[AB]{3,}`, the group will have no choice but to match the first "A" and leave the rest for the remaining part of the pattern ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uM6q4y/1)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who commented. Turns out a regex match only has one way of matching its groups, due to * or + being greedy quantifiers, and using them will make them try to match as much string as they can. So that leaves my question irrelevant, but nevertheless answered.